# Angular, undefined external libraries when writing directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm not sure if this is exactly the issue, but I will try to be as clear as possible. I am trying to write a directive using this http://codepen.io/amergin/pen/cKAqv example with packery. So what I have done is create an external directive in my/directives directory in my app and literally just copied the working directive into my own.  The issue I am having is grunt does not seem to like this one bit. My directory file looks like this (I removed the inside for times sake but its literally the same as the codepen example)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('demoApp')
.directive('packeryAngular', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
return {
//contents in here
 }

 });
```

And grunt doesn't seem to like this one bit and is returning this -

```
app/scripts/directives/packeryangular.js
line 17  col 36  'Packery' is not defined.
line 24  col 32  'Draggabilly' is not defined.
line 37  col 13  '$' is not defined.
line 38  col 15  '$' is not defined.
line 48  col 32  'Draggabilly' is not defined.
line 13  col 38  'attrs' is defined but never used.
line 27  col 62  'pointer' is defined but never used.
line 27  col 55  'event' is defined but never used.
line 27  col 45  'instance' is defined but never used.
line 52  col 62  'pointer' is defined but never used.
line 52  col 55  'event' is defined but never used.
line 52  col 45  'instance' is defined but never used.
```

So I am pretty new to all this, and I'm not entirely sure what to do with this information. Is it ok that packery and draggabilly are not defined, even though I'm 100% sure the libraries are loaded in on the main app? It's saying the jquery $ are not defined, I'm thinking it's the same sort of issue because I'm also sure that library is loaded on too. It seems pretty straight forward so I can't quite understand why I'm running into these problems. Would appreciate any help, and thanks very much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is jshint results.

It is not actual errors - it is possible errors detected by js jshint.

About "is not defined" errors - you can define you globals in .jshintrc as following:

`"globals": {
    "Packery": false,
    "Draggabilly": false,
    "$": false
  }`

About "is defined but never used" - it is hints about useless variables defined in your code(variable is defined but actually never used - in general it can be safely removed)

If you want - you can disable this hints by seetting `"unused": false` in your .jshintrc

Comment: Sorry to be a pain - this is still very new for me. Would I be doing this in the gruntfile?

Comment: no, there should be `.jshintrc` file (typicaly in same folder as gruntfile), and path to this file should be specified in jshint grunt plugin config (if you are using something generator-angular, you already have this)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling with that for a long time!!